# Querydsl using union to get the total sum of a column

Tags: querydsl, predicate

I'm using queryDSL 4.1.3. I want to get the sum of a same column but while changing the selection criteria. Which I would like to do is the equivalent of this SQL Query:

```
select sum(emp) from 
(select sum(employee) as emp from table1 where column1 = 'value1'              
 unionAll 
 select sum(employee) as emp from table1 where column2 = 'value2')
```

I would point out that I should have the possibilty to select either sum(employee) or -sum(employee) depending on a condition which I have in my code.

I  browsed the documentation here: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/reference/html/ and I couldn't find how to do it and whether it's possible or not.

Anyone has an idea? many thanks in advance.

Comment: With SQL, I tried another approch. using joins instead. Something like the following: SELECT E.NR,SUM(employee)
FROM
table T1  LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT NR, SUM(employee) as emp from table group by nr) T2
ON T1.NR= T2.NR

group by T1.NR . My question is : is it possible to use subqueries in left joins?

Comment: This would double count `employee` from a record with `column1 = 'value1' AND column2 = 'value2'`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much @RobertBain for the reply. Which I want is to get the sum of "employee" for the first condition column1 = "value1"  + the sum of "employee" for the second condition column2="value2". the query in your answer would work perfectly if my real query wasn't a little bit complicated than the query in the question :  the sum could be negative depending on a condition. I think I'll have to edit my question.

Comment: If you can tell me what the condition is I will update my answer.

Comment: I have a boolean variable "add" when it's true then I should select sum(employee) otherwise I shoud substract sum(employees) so I select -sum(employee).

Comment: Is that a database column or in your application layer?

Comment: Actually it's in my database but in onther table but I'm returning its value in a variable in my application layer.

Comment: You need to make the question much clearer, I'm going delete my answer because obviously it's not helpful.